How can I write a jest unit test for the addEventListener method?
I want to write a jest unit test to test this method.
export async function setEventListeners(dateBlob, log) {
  let [nextClicked] = getButtons();


  if (nextClicked && nextClicked[0]?.getAttribute("listener") !== "true") {
    nextClicked[0]?.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("nextclicked");
      createBlob("#weekly", dateBlob);
      nextClicked[0]?.setAttribute("listener", "true");
    });
   }
  }


export function getButtons(){
  let nextClicked = document.querySelectorAll(".next");
  return [nextClicked];
}

What I currently wrote is this
describe("unit tests", () => {
       test('setEventListeners: should call createBlob on click', async () => {


let createBlobSpy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'createBlob');

const mockButton = {
  addEventListener: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((handler) => {
    handler();
  }),
};
document.querySelector = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mockButton);
instance.setEventListeners(mockBlob, "1");



expect(createBlobSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();


});

}
However this fails because the test does not trigger the click correctly I believe. Could anyone assist?
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0


If you can mock the createBlob function, could you also mock the getButtons and directly returns the mockButton ? It could limit the possible causes why your function is not called. When testing, you should rely on the least amount of things you don't control. So you can easily figure out what's wrong when the test fails.

This is the wrong way to test this. Pull your anonymous callback out into a named function. Write a test that tests that function. Then write a test that attaches a mock of your named callback to the DOM element. Trigger a click and make sure the fake function gets called. You will know the real callback works from your test of it, and you will know that the callback gets called when the element is clicked from your mocked out test. Don't try to do it all at once, because then the tests are a) harder to write b) more fragile and c) more tightly coupled to the implementation.
